# Trying to convert string looking like "ÐÐ°Ð²Ð»ÑÐº ÐÑÐºÑÐ¾Ñ" to correctly looking string

Tags: swift, unicode, encoding

I've got a problem converting string looking like "ÐÐ°Ð²Ð»ÑÐº ÐÑÐºÑÐ¾Ñ" to correctly looking string.

I'm trying to use such way:

```
func stringToUTF16String (stringaDaConvertire stringa: String) -> String {

        let encodedData = stringa.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding)!
        let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
       let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!


        //println(attributedString.string)
        return attributedString.string
    }
```

But I got a compiler error: "Type of expression is ambisious withou more context" on that row:

```
 let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
```

Comment: What do you mean by correctly looking string ?

Comment: test- ÐÑÐ°ÑÐ¸ ÐÐ°Ð´ÑÐºÑÐ½Ð¸
test- ÐÐ°ÑÐ¿Ð°ÑÐ¸ Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð³ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¸ ÑÑÑÐ±Ð¾Ð» I got such string. I need to represent them in UTF-8 to make them look like:  
"test- Брати Гадюкіни test- Карпати програли футбол"